# Loading default drag and drop cursors into my app

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, ole, mouse-cursor

I am trying to implement drag and drop in my listview control so I can rearrange items.

I want to use system default cursors to indicate when drop is/isn't allowed.

I have checked documentation for [`LoadCursor function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391(v=vs.85).aspx) and have found nothing.

*The best resemblance I could find was for the case when drop is not allowed -> `IDC_NO` has the same look as the cursor in OLE drag and drop, but it is red ( I have tested this on my Windows 7).*

### QUESTION:

How to use `LoadCursor` (or some similar function) to load default cursors used in OLE drag and drop?

Comment: When implementing drag & drop via OLE you get the cursors for free by returning `DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS` from `IDropSource::GiveFeedback`. I'm assuming you are not actually doing drag & drop via OLE though?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: *I'm assuming you are not actually doing drag & drop via OLE though?*  No I do not, I thought that was clear. I apologize for being ambiguous.  I have no experience with COM/OLE. I am also trying to implement drag and drop via OLE, but that should be another question. Searching online, I have found no examples of this in pure WinAPI and C/C++.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm judging from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826522/detect-when-scrolling-is-necessary-while-user-drags-listview-items) that you have, and I'm curious about the answer...

Comment: @andlabs: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/880541/Loading-default-drag-and-drop-cursors-into-my-app?arn=0) answer is promising, I just don't have time to test it... I believe it is the right way, I just need to figure out when to free library...

Answer (score 0):

If you use LoadCursor, then you must set it later with SetCursor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: While this may be short and uses a link as reference, I do think this is an attempt to answer their question. This came up on the low quality review queues, and I imagine the reason being is because you didn't give much of an explanation for how you came about that answer. I would recommend adding a little more detail next time.

Comment: The OP is asking how to load a particular set of cursors, not how to display them once loaded. SetCursor is not relevant to loading the OLE drag and drop cursors and there is no information on the linked page that can help answer the question.