# Detect when scrolling is necessary while user drags listview items

Tags: c++, c, listview, winapi, drag-and-drop

### INTRODUCTION:

I am implementing rearranging of listview items without using OLE drag and drop.

### PROBLEM:

I have successfully solved most of this task, except scrolling up/down when user wants to drop items at the position that is not currently visible.

### QUESTION:

I am able to scroll up/down listview by using following messages:

```
SendMessage(hwndListView, WM_VSCROLL, (WPARAM)SB_LINEUP, (LPARAM)0);
SendMessage(hwndListView, WM_VSCROLL, (WPARAM)SB_LINEDOWN, (LPARAM)0);
```

I need your advice in figuring out *when and where* I need to send those messages ( I suppose it should be done on WM_MOUSEHOVER or something like that? ).

**I just do not know on which message, and how, I should check if scrolling is needed.**

*I am interested in implementing default scrolling behavior for drag and drop.*

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

I have tried to use listview hit testing so I can examine [LVHITTESTINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774754(v=vs.85).aspx) for `LVHT_ABOVE` and `LVHT_BELOW` but that did not work for me.

*I was never able to get those values when clicking on listview...*

I have found some examples in other programming languages that use timers to implement this. I am studying them as I write this post.

### ADDITIONAL INFO:

Listview is in report mode and supports multiselection.

I am handling following messages:

```
LVN_BEGINDRAG  // I create drag image here
WM_MOUSEMOVE   // I update drag image here
WM_LBUTTONUP   // I rearrange items here and perform cleanup
```

I have omitted SSCCE to keep this post short. If needed I can post it. If further info is required please leave a comment.

Comment: Very well asked question +1.

Comment: You don't need to know, whether or not scrolling is needed. Simply send an [LVM_ENSUREVISIBLE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774902.aspx) or use the [ListView_EnsureVisible macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761240.aspx), and the ListView does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @IInspectable: I disagree. Can you elaborate your suggestion please?

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted your question. I was under the impression that you were looking for a way to bring the newly inserted item into view, but you are really looking for information while the drag-and-drop operation is still in flight. One remark strikes me as odd, though: You note that you never received the relevant hit testing flags when clicking **on** the ListView. This is to be expected. Those flags are only present, when you check for a position **outside** the ListView's client area.

Comment: @IInspectable: *hose flags are only present, when you check for a position outside the ListView's client area.* Indeed, but I get `LHT_ABOVE` **when clicking on subitem**, but never when clicking above the listview. This must be relevant to mention. If needed I can post demonstration code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably your drag and drop loop uses `SetCapture` to capture mouse input.

All you have to do is watch for `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages. When the mouse moves above the top or below the bottom of the listview, set a flag to indicate you are scrolling and start a timer using `SetTimer`.

Every time the timer goes off, scroll one line in the appropriate direction, by sending the listview a `WM_VSCROLL` message.

If the mouse moves back inside the listview, or the capture is lost (i.e. you get `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`), kill your timer and stop scrolling.

Comment: Do you know of any canonical examples that implement this?  I fully understand the logic, but I'm trying to come up with a clean implementation.  In my scenario, the user can drag-to-scroll in all 4 directions.  I'm just not sure how many timer ids and flags this should require.

Comment: @user15284017 I would have thought you'd only need one; every time the timer fires you can check the cursor position and scroll based on that.